# Resolving hipchat gradle dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

Please pardon my ignorance. But I am trying to use hipchat api. I am trying to follow:

- https://github.com/campnic/jHipChat

It has a pom.xml with following content:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.github.hipchat</groupId>
<artifactId>jHipchat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I want to have a gradle equivalent for it. Please help me. If I try to use the above group and name, then gradle build fails with :

> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
>
> > Could not find com.github.hipchat:jHipchat:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.   Required by:
> >       :new_core:unspecified

Please help.

Relevant parts of build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        compile group:'com.github.hipchat', name: 'jHipchat', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I tried git clone the hipchat source and did mvn package. But it could not build successfully with various failures.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your Gradle build script, including the `repositories` and `dependencies` declarations.

Comment: I am wondering is it even possible to get hipchat from maven....I tried searching maven with hipchat and could not find. I am new to this so struggling. All I want is to get jHipChat jar included in my classpath so that I can use their api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library in question is at 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and doesn't seem to be published to a public Maven repository. What you can do is to build the library yourself (`mvn install`) and then pull it into Gradle by declaring a `mavenLocal()` repository.